# How do I reassemble a zip file that has been emailed in multiple parts?

Tags: zip, archiving, 7-zip, winzip

I received 3 emails each containing part of a zip file. The extensions end in .z00, .z01 and .z02. (Emailed as such to get around the typical 10Mb attachment limit per email.)

I have put all 3 files into one directory.

I can use both 7-zip and WinZip to open the first file (the .z00 file) and it lists the contents of the zip but when trying to extract the files both programs are reporting errors.

What is the least error prone way of reassembling this zip and getting to the files?

Comment: Many of the answers point out that all you should need to do is unzip the *first* file while the others are in the same folder (and that concatenation should not be required).  I remember split files where the first (or last?) file was .zip instead of .z##.  Changing the file extensions to match that pattern might get it working properly.  (Try changing your .z01 to .zip, and if that does not work, try also changing your .z02 to .z01 and your .z03 to .z02.  If *that* doesn't work, try *ending* the series with .zip (starting with either .z01 or .z00).

Comment: Thankfully someone did answer the reassemble the zip question. I'm using it today to get around a 7ZIP/CPANEL issue (7zip doesn't want to make a 100gb zip file, cpanel doesn't want to unzip split files )

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's fairly safe to assume that the file parts just need to be concatenated together.

The easiest way to do this is within 7-Zip - navigate to the folder in the 7-Zip file manager, right-click on the first file in the sequence, and select "Combine Files..." from the context menu.

It can also be easily done on the command line.

On Windows:

```
copy /B input.z* output.zip
```

Or Linux (or if you've got Unix command line tools on Windows using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)):

```
cat input.z* > output.zip
```

Comment: In my case for windows : 7zip did not work, but manual cmd command did work. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Usually there is one *.zip in the set and a couple of *.z??.
If you open the *.zip the others are unziped as well as long as they are in the same 
directory.

If this does not work try what [therefromhere](https://superuser.com/questions/15935/how-do-i-reassemble-a-zip-file-that-has-been-emailed-in-multiple-parts/15940#15940)
said, or if you are on windows:

> `copy /B yourfile.z00 + yourfile.z01 + yourfile.z02 yourfile.zip`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to unzip all the files? Usually, one have to unzip just one (the first or the last).
Maybe, if you change the extesion of the `.z00` to `.zip`, will be able to unzip all.

Comment: yeah, that works for me too

Answer (score 4):

Usually when i receive split files , i unzip the first file only.

 Doing so gave me the complete file, I used 7-zip

Answer (score 3):

I had difficulty with two files I received as xx.zip and xx.z01. I simply did:

```
cat xx.01 xx.zip > yy.zip
```

followed by

```
unzip yy.zip
```

Gave a few warnings, but did the job. This was on Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: This certainly isn't 'the least error-prone' alternative.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they were just split directly, with no extra information, so you should be able to just concatenate them and end up with a full zip file. [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900565) has some links to tools that can concatenate files.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Using 7z**

1. Open the folder where the split folders are stored. In my case they were 16 files named from *.7z.001 to *.7z.016
2. Right-click on the first of the folders and left click to select the "Extract To" suggested folder name proposed automatically by 7z.
3. 7z then creates a new uncompressed folder inside the same folder and starts unzipping and combining all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new folder, drag the split files into that folder.  Highlight all files, select Extract.  This will create a new sup-folder where your combined files will be located.  Used 7-zip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing seems rather unique, and could maybe be a problem about how the files where packed / the zips themselves.

In my case (2023), everything worked like a charm - although I didn't have any 00 file.

##### My first file was 001 and I extracted that like I normally do with 7zip as well (for example.zip "extract to example/") - this extracted all files into the ["example/"] directory.

This is not a new zip file of course, if you wanted that, *although i guess your problem is long solved ;)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Open your 7-zip file manager and and navigate to where the parts are, you can then highlight, right click and extract here or wherever you want the end file to be located.

Comment: Please re-read the question, OP has advised he is getting an error when trying to working with the set as a whole

Answer (score -2):

Plain combining 2 individual archives into one will not work. In fact I just tried that on zip, bzip2 and xz archives. All reported the outcome archive to be invalid. It might work with proper multi-part archives though.