# Unzip Multipart Zip from Command Line

Tags: macos, terminal, zip

Thanks in advance for any help.  I am trying to unzip a multipart zip file from the command line in OSX 10.8.5.

I created the zip using `zip -s 800m foo.zip foo.mov`

The file `foo.mov` is 2.7GB.  So I have the files: `foo.zip, foo.z01, foo.z02, foo.z03`.

I tried using `zip -s 0 foo.zip -O foo_unsplit.zip`, but then foo_unsplit.zip is only 1.6GB and gives the error below when used with unzip.

```
error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
```

I also tried using `cat Heritage.zip Heritage.z01 Heritage.z02 Heritage.z03 > Heritage_unsplit.zip` but unzipping the result file gives the below result:

```
unzip Heritage_unsplit.zip 
Archive:  Heritage_unsplit.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of Heritage_unsplit.zip or
        Heritage_unsplit.zip.zip, and cannot find Heritage_unsplit.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Does anyone know of a way to unzip a multipart file in command line.  Have I made a mistake in any of my attempts?

Comment: If the concatenation doesn't work, you may have a corrupt file somewhere. See http://superuser.com/questions/15935/how-do-i-reassemble-a-zip-file-that-has-been-emailed-in-multiple-parts

Comment: I now think that this is just the 2GB single file limit of zip archives.

Comment: See also [How do I split a .zip file into multiple segments?](http://superuser.com/questions/336219/how-do-i-split-a-zip-file-into-multiple-segments). I extracted a 6GB folder from a set of 500 MB split zips.

Comment: See also [Extract large zip file (50 GB) on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/114011/extract-large-zip-file-50-gb-on-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is different between MacOS versions - I'm currently running *High Sierra*  and `unzip` is still not supporting multipart properly - but I did the same trick with `cat` but in reverse order and it worked.

i.e. `cat Heritage.z03 Heritage.z02 Heritage.z01 Heritage.zip > Heritage_unsplit.zip`
Then `unzip` on it worked.

I got some errors like the ones below, but the files are binary equal:

```
> unzip big.zip
Archive:  big.zip
warning [big.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
warning [big.zip]:  1073741824 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  1073741828
  (attempting to re-compensate)
  inflating: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed order while `cat` files, order should be:

`cat foo.z01, foo.z02, foo.z03 foo.zip > unsplited_foo.zip`

and after use `unzip`:

`unzip unsplited_foo.zip`